# Selenium get the exact XPath based on the class and following input tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have multiple calendar controls on my form where the html is as follows

```
<div class="flatpickr-calendar animate arrowTop open" tabindex="-1" style="top: 559.1px; left: 173.8px; right: auto;">
  <div class="flatpickr-months">
    <span class="flatpickr-prev-month">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
        <g></g>
        <path d="M5.207 8.471l7.146 7.147-0.707 0.707-7.853-7.854 7.854-7.853 0.707 0.707-7.147 7.146z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <div class="flatpickr-month">
      <div class="flatpickr-current-month">
        <select class="flatpickr-monthDropdown-months" tabindex="-1">
          <option class="flatpickr-monthDropdown-month" value="0" tabindex="-1">January</option>
          <option class="flatpickr-monthDropdown-month" value="1" tabindex="-1">February</option>
          <option class="flatpickr-monthDropdown-month" value="2" tabindex="-1">March</option>
        </select>
        <div class="numInputWrapper">
          <input class="numInput cur-year" type="number" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Year" max="2023">
          <span class="arrowUp"></span>
          <span class="arrowDown"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="flatpickr-next-month flatpickr-disabled">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
        <g></g>
        <path d="M13.207 8.472l-7.854 7.854-0.707-0.707 7.146-7.146-7.146-7.148 0.707-0.707 7.854 7.854z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="flatpickr-innerContainer">
    <div class="flatpickr-rContainer">
      <div class="flatpickr-weekdays">
        <div class="flatpickr-weekdaycontainer">
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday"> Sun</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday">Mon</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday">Tue</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday">Wed</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday">Thu</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday">Fri</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-weekday">Sat </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flatpickr-days" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="dayContainer">
          <span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="February 26, 2023" tabindex="-1">26</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="February 27, 2023" tabindex="-1">27</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="February 28, 2023" tabindex="-1">28</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 1, 2023" tabindex="-1">1</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 2, 2023" tabindex="-1">2</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 3, 2023" tabindex="-1">3</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 4, 2023" tabindex="-1">4</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 5, 2023" tabindex="-1">5</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 6, 2023" tabindex="-1">6</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 7, 2023" tabindex="-1">7</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 8, 2023" tabindex="-1">8</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 9, 2023" tabindex="-1">9</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 10, 2023" tabindex="-1">10</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 11, 2023" tabindex="-1">11</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day " aria-label="March 12, 2023" tabindex="-1">12</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day today" aria-label="March 13, 2023" aria-current="date" tabindex="-1">13</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 14, 2023">14</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 15, 2023">15</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 16, 2023">16</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 17, 2023">17</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 18, 2023">18</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 19, 2023">19</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 20, 2023">20</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 21, 2023">21</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 22, 2023">22</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 23, 2023">23</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 24, 2023">24</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 25, 2023">25</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 26, 2023">26</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 27, 2023">27</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 28, 2023">28</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 29, 2023">29</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 30, 2023">30</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="March 31, 2023">31</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 1, 2023">1</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 2, 2023">2</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 3, 2023">3</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 4, 2023">4</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 5, 2023">5</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 6, 2023">6</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 7, 2023">7</span>
          <span class="flatpickr-day nextMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="April 8, 2023">8</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to select the input inside the opened calendar as follows

```
//div[contains(@class,'arrowTop open')]//following::input[contains(@class,'numInput cur-year')]
```

[image]

I am seeing multiple element where I would like to see only one, so how can I correct the XPath to correct this and select the required

Comment: When you post HTML, please take a minute to use an HTML beautifier before posting so that it's more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `following::` from the xpath, in order to obtain:

```
//div[contains(@class,'arrowTop open')]//input[contains(@class,'numInput cur-year')]
```

To understand what `following` does, look at the following example. Basically it matches all the elements in the HTML which are found below the current node.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without more of the HTML or a link to the page but you can significantly simplify your locator by using a CSS selector,

```
div.flatpickr-calendar.open input
```

That will select only the INPUT inside the `.open` DIV.

If you must have an XPath, I've simplified it down to

```
//div[contains(@class,'open')]//input
```